# How do I change the displayed wx.DirPickerCtrl path?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I would like to change the value of a wxPython DirPickerCtrl at runtime. In the example below I am trying to change the value using SetPath() (second last line in code) but the value does not change in the display.

Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import wx
import wx.xrc


class MyFrame2 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_dirPicker3 = wx.DirPickerCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, u"Select a folder", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.DIRP_DEFAULT_STYLE )
        bSizer6.Add( self.m_dirPicker3, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer6 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass




class App(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame2(parent=None)
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()

    # Trying to change path here
    app.frame.m_dirPicker3.SetPath('/')

    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It works on Windows 7, wxPython 2.8.

Comment: This question is lying around unanswered.   How's it going.... did you solve your problem?   If not ... what platform are you one, what versions of wx etc...

Comment: Sort of... It _seems_ to be a bug in the GTK implementation of wxWidgets. There's a few odd things going on with the DirPickerCtrl. The change directory events don't seem to fire using the drop-down selection but do fire if the directory chooser dialog is opened (in which case the widget is updated correctly). I've been meaning to look into it more but have been distracted by more interesting things :-P  I'm running Debian Jessie with Gnome 3 and wxPython v2.8.12.1